# Getting value of column in selected rows from list

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, ribbon

I am trying to get selected rows in the list and select ids for the pdf generator. Debug stops after context.load(rows) and nothing happens after that till I reload the page.
If remove code for selecting many ids and select just one and write context.load(row) - it works good. So how to get more than one row?

Elements.xml:

```
    <CustomAction Id="CustomAction"
        RegistrationId="100"
        RegistrationType="List"
        Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
        Rights="ManageLists"
        Sequence="25"
        Title="Generate pdf">
        <CommandUIExtension>
            <CommandUIDefinitions>
                <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">
                    <Button Id="GeneratePdf"
                        Alt="Generate pdf by template"
                        Description="Generate pdf by template"
                        Sequence="25"
                        Command="GeneratePdf"
                        LabelText="Generate pdf"
                        TemplateAlias="o1" />
                </CommandUIDefinition>
            </CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIHandlers>
                <CommandUIHandler Command="GeneratePdf"
                    EnabledScript="javascript:
                    function enableGeneratePdf() {
                        var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
                        return (items.length >= 1);
                    }
                    enableGeneratePdf();"
                    CommandAction="javascript:
                    function getSelectedIds() {
                        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                        var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
                        var selectedItems = '';
                        for (index in items) {
                            selectedItems = selectedItems + ',' + items[index].id;
                        }
                        return selectedItems.substring(1, selectedItems.length);
                    }
//GeneratePdf('{SelectedListId}');
                    GeneratePdf(getSelectedIds());" />
            </CommandUIHandlers>
        </CommandUIExtension>
    </CustomAction>
    <Control Id="AdditionalPageHead" ControlSrc="~/_controltemplates/generator.ascx" Sequence="25"/>
```

here is generator.ascx:

```
    <script language="ecmascript" type="text/ecmascript">
        var docsList;
        var web;
        var context;
        var rows;
//var row;
        var columnName = "Title";

        function GeneratePdf(rowNumbers) {
            context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            web = context.get_web();
            docsList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Documents");
            var ids = rowNumbers.split(',');
            rows = new Array(ids.length);
            var count = 0;      
            for (index in ids) {
                rows[count] = docsList.getItemById(index);
                count++;
            }
            //row = docsList.getItemById(rowNumber);
            context.load(web);
            context.load(docsList);
            context.load(rows);
            //context.load(row);
            context.executeQueryAsync(OnDocumentsListsLoaded);
        }

        function OnDocumentsListsLoaded() {
            var ids = '';
            for (index in rows) {
                ids = ids + ',' + row.get_item(columnName);
            }
            //var id = row.get_item(columnName);
            window.location = "/_layouts/Documents/DownloadGeneratedPdf.aspx?ids=" + ids.substring(1, ids.length);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to call context.load on each row instead of on the array?

Comment: Does the DownloadGeneratedPdf.aspx really expect a list of Titles in the query parameter ids?

Comment: @PerJakobsen 1)yes, the same result 2) yes, the first column called 'Title', but this is id actually at developing stage

Comment: In the function OnDocumentsListsLoaded the for loop defines the "index" variable, but "row" is used instead.

Comment: @Matthias thank you, but it is not a critical error, ecma script supports this code and will fail at this line, but OnDocumentsListsLoaded function does not start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, there was my mistake.
Here is working code of generator.ascx:

```
    function GeneratePdf(rowNumbers) {
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = context.get_web();
        docsList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Documents");
        var ids = rowNumbers.split(',');
        rows = [];

        context.load(web);
        context.load(docsList);
        for (i in ids) {
            rows[i] = docsList.getItemById(ids[i]);
            context.load(rows[i]);
        }

        context.executeQueryAsync(OnDocumentsListsLoaded);
    }

    function OnDocumentsListsLoaded() {
        var ids = [];
        for (i in rows) {
            ids.push(rows[i].get_item(columnName));
        }
        window.location = "/_layouts/Documents/DownloadGeneratedPdf.aspx?ids=" + JSON.stringify(ids);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var currentListGUID = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();

var list = web.get_lists().getById(currentListGUID);

var rows = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{                           
  var row = list.getItemById(items[i].id);
  ctx.load(row);
  rows.push(row);
}

ctx.executeQueryAsync(function ()
{                    
 var ids = '';
 for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
 {
   var r = rows[i];
   ids = ids + ',' + r.get_item('Title');
 }
 alert(ids);
},

function(sender, args)
{
  alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, but after first for loop (before ctx.executeQueryAsync) the rows variable has length 0.